# KNative with Istio Listening on Port 8080

Tags: knative, knative-serving

I have setup Istio's "ingress gateway" to listen on 8080, and have issues with running the Knative hello-world. Has anyone setup Knative like this?

I would like internet traffic coming in to port 8080 to show the output of the Knative hello world.

Comment: Are you asking about the user container, or about the common HTTP ingress for the Knative cluster?

Comment: The ingress gateway's port is unrelated to the port that the user containers run on -- Envoy (used by Istio) will happily use a backend on a different port if directed to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an existing container which listens on port 80 instead of `$PORT`, you can set [`spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[0].containerPort`](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/spec/knative-api-specification-1.0/#containerport) to indicate which port the container listens on.

For example:

```yaml
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: helloworld-go
 namespace: default
spec:
 template:
  spec:
   containers:
    - image: gcr.io/knative-samples/helloworld-go
      env:
      - name: TARGET
       value: "Go Sample v1"
      ports:
      - containerPort: 80
```

Knative will automatically set the `$PORT` environment variable to the requested container port, so setting containerPort should work with any of the Knative samples.

Comment: I did experiment a bit trying to set `PORT` in Yaml, the knative api rejected, I think that's expected behavior.

Comment: You need to set the `containerPort`, and Knative will automatically set the environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question this is similar to an issue I've run into trying to configure Knative with the Istio ingress gateway on non-standard ports. Following the Knative instructions for Istio integration I applied the Knative Istio controller (net-istio). This includes a `networking.istio.io Gateway` that selects `istio: ingressgateway` that specifies port 80. Modifying this resource to the correct port (8080 in the question) should fix the issue.